# error: object DataFrame is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark-shell to run examples of Spark (use Scala), I import the library

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext, DataFrame}
```

and I got the error:

```
error: object DataFrame is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql
```

I don't know why, I checked on http://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-1.3.0-rc1-docs/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I found the reason, because my spark version is 1.2.0